# Angular Errors on ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when I try to run my angular application using `ng serve` I get these error:

> Failed to compile.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305:
>   Module '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has
>   no exported member 'Subscription'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/audit-trail.d.ts(2,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/changes.d.ts(1,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/loaded.d.ts(3,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/snapshot-changes.d.ts(1,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/state-changes.d.ts(2,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/observable/fromRef.d.ts(2,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Dell/myProject/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(13,31): error
>   TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'firestore'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.

I am making my first angular application following the tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase-4504ff7717c1) Can anyone tell me what is the problem here as I have followed each step carefully up to the adding of bootstrap nav-bar. And then when I run it again it gives me these errors but before adding bootstrap it was running fine.

Comment: you are working with `rxjs` 6 a lot has changed in the newer version keep yourself updated mate see this https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. My problem is now fixed and it was fixed after i did whole thing from start by using @latest instead of specifying any versions. Thanks A.Winnen and Vikas.

Answer (score 2):

Your seem to use Angular6 with RxjS v6.xx but one of your libraries need rxjs-compat because it do not support the new rxjs v6 yet.

run in the directory where package.json is located:

```
npm i rxjs-compat -S
```

Comment: This did removed those errors .. but now i got this on app.
`Cannot GET /`
and in cli:
`ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(13,31): error TS2694
: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'firestore'.`